# how to solve the gitbash clone fatal error

Tags: github, git-bash

I'm a beginner to GitHub.I need to clone the  https://github.com/UFPA/abc.git . when i typed the code
git clone https://github.com/UFPA/ufpa.git
It gives me the error

Cloning into 'ufpa'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/UFPA/ufpa.git/': Failed to connect to 172.22.254.57 port 1080 after 2071 ms: Connection refused

It will be firewall issue? because my system port is 8080 and the error show the port 1080.

Comment: Have you tried https version of the git url?

Comment: yes  i tried it.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address 172.22.254.57 is in private IP address range. So most likely it is a proxy server in your organization.

Also, the Github organization [UFPA](https://github.com/UFPA) doesn't seem have any public repositories. Unless you have access to private repositories in this organization, you will get "repository not found" error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear my doubts.