# I how to resolve git clone fails in 443

Tags: github, git-bash

It's my first useing  git I want to clone "unfp",
so i use $ git clone https://github.com/UNF/unfp.git

Cloning into 'unfp'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/UNF/unfp.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443

but it show the error
I need your help.

Comment: Do you have access to the repository on the website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right .gitconfig syntax for http.sslCAInfo certificate for specific server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293417/what-is-the-right-gitconfig-syntax-for-http-sslcainfo-certificate-for-specific)

Comment: You asked pretty much the same question 2 days ago. Does this answer your question? [how to solve the gitbash clone fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699597/how-to-solve-the-gitbash-clone-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

you may have to setup SSO/SSH for authentication

Comment: please update your answer with explanations according to Stackoverflow guidelines!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).